# What is the Visual Basic equivalent for C# virtual

Tags: c#, vb.net, model-view-controller

The MVC tutorial written for C# lists this property for a product:

```
public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
```

How do I express this in Visual Basic?  I tried:

```
public virtual Category as Category
```

but it didn't fly.  The editor underlines the first "Category" expecting an end of statement.

Comment: Try Overridable

Answer (score 3):

It's `Overridable`

`Public Overridable Property Category as Category`

[reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/overridable)